# Is there such a thing as a Google Brand Account in existence?

Tags: youtube, google-account, youtube-channel, google-account-profile, google-brand-account

When I try to create a Google brand account, it directs me to a Google support page called "*Move YouTube channel to Brand Account*", and on that page there is  written - quote: "*If your YouTube channel is connected to your personal Google Account, you can move it to be connected to a new or existing Brand Account*."

Well, when I try to create it, it again just directs me to this same google support page - "*Move YouTube channel to Brand Account*".

But another quote from that same page suggests that a Google brand account is something which you can actually create and have: "*If you already have a YouTube channel, you can associate it with a specific Brand Account*."

Are they talking about a YouTube Brand Channel?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it refers to an issue happing before changes done to Brand Accounts. Since August 4, 2021 new Brand Accounts can only be linked to YouTube channels.  Ref. [Manage your Brand Account](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/7001996?hl=en).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Brand Channel on Youtube [from this link](https://www.youtube.com/channel_switcher). You will need to be logged-in.

Once you've created the Brand Channel then you can move an existing personal page or brand to this new Brand Channel. It's a good idea to [read the instructions](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/3056283?hl=en) you've referenced on how to move channels because there are caveats.